# Windows 10 audio fades out

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I'm having an issue with Windows 10 audio: when listening to something/watching a movie the audio automatically fades out and drops to a lower volume. To be clear, the volume indication in Windows doesn't change, i.e. if it was set to 50 at the beginning it'll remain fixed at 50, but it can be heard drastically decreasing.

If the source is paused and then played back again, the sound will begin playing at the higher volume to fade out again a few seconds later.

Things I've tried so far - suggested by the many post I read about:

- Uninstalling/reinstalling both NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device WDM and Realtek drivers
- Using only one driver at a time
- Installing older driver versions
- Installing the driver in compatibility (W8) mode
- Reinstalling the drivers from the PC manufacturer (Dell)

None of these worked. Needless to say, it's very frustrating. I must keep the speakers turned off, otherwise notifications will blast out at 100dB unexpectedly whilst listening to music for more than 5 secs will turn the sound into a whisper.

If someone knows of a solution or had this issue before, I'd be so glad to hear about it.

Thanks

Comment: does it happen if you are using headphones as well ??

Comment: @Elmo nope, with headphones everything is fine.

Comment: which pc/laptop are u using and what version of windows 10 ?? AND had to upgraded this PC from windows 7 or 8 to windows 10 or did you do a clean install. Many people who upgraded from 7 or 8 to windows 10 have had this issue ?

Comment: go through this page https://www.techjunkie.com/windows-reducing-system-volume/

Comment: @Elmo already tried that solution and currently running the "do nothing" option, but still... the PC is a Dell G5 15 which came with Windows 10 out of the box.

Comment: I solved it!
You have to disable all devices at “Recording tab” - Read this comment from the link that I had sent you.Give it a try, disable you microphone

Comment: another comment :PROBLEM SOLVED FOR ME WINDOWS 10 PRO
I went to Playback devices -> Speakers ( or whatever is your main device) Properties – > Advanced + Set the format to 24bit 44100Hz. I have unchecked both in the Exclusive mode
Than go to Recording Devices ( you can do this from the speaker section on the right bottom of your screen -> On Microphone right click and properties -> Go to Advanced and set Default format to 2 Channel, 16bit, 44100Hz (On recording device i left checked both in Exclusive mode)
***THAN RESTART PC***
After that you shoudve been fine ! Hope it works. Cheers!

Comment: there are many more solutions over there in the comments ...go through them ....if nothing helps ,I suggest you format and clean install windows 10.

Comment: Just messed around with Wave MaxxAudioPro console and looks like disabling theie EQ profile did the job... will test if this keeps working, then will report here.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I can help someone else with this, I solved the issue from my onkyo stereo. I tried everything, from mainboard drivers to sound drivers, only keep the main sound device active, revert changes, all of them didn't work. I reset my onkyo stereo by the two button combination, disabled center speaker and subwoofer, changed output to CD and the problem was solved.